# 135 tcp port blocked but still listening

Tags: firewall, port, tcp, blocking

I did:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule dir=in action=block protocol=TCP localport=135 name="Block_TCP-135"
```

rebooted my Windows 10

typed:

```
netstat -n -a | findstr "LISTENING" | findstr ":135"
```

but I still get:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -n -a | findstr "LISTENING" | findstr ":135"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

(still listening)

So how to block (stop listening) this port?

**Update**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -nab

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  RpcSs
```

135 is used by `RpcSs` (**Remote Procedure Call (RPC)** Service)

Many internet resources recommends NOT to disable this service

Comment: Find which program use it. Disable or delete it. Use -b with netstat command.

Comment: @Biswa `Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Service - RpcSs` but I guess I should not disable it?

Comment: Disable Netbios and Wins services in network interface properties. You may also doable DHCP if not required.